# Resume activity instead of creating the new one with custom URLScheme

Tags: android, android-activity, custom-url

I'm opening an application with custom URLScheme. The problem is, that when there is already an instance of app/activities in this app, when clicking HOME and running application from URL, the new instance of app is created.
The question is: how do I finish all the activities already created and running before launching the app again?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nomtek.activities">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FunctionsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="ax4s" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FunctionActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_function">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BarcodeCaptureActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode_capute"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post you AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes! post AndroidManifest.xml it will be helpful.

Comment: androidmanifest pasted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `SharedPreferences` for that. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: that could be solution, but what if android kills activity because it's not used for a long time?

Comment: Then Your application will generate new instance which will be first at that time. :)

Comment: yes, but variable stays set though, doesn't it? so code will call finish() anyway